# На контрольной точке в 760 px при адаптации footer и header не растягиваются на весь экран. Как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, media

На контрольной точке в 760 px при адаптации footer и header не растягиваются на весь экран. Как это исправить?

```css
body{
            margin:0;
        }
        .container{
            max-width:980px;
            height:auto;
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        img{
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        header{
            min-width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#c2c2c2;
        }
        .block{
            width:170px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top:20px;
               
        }
        button{
            width:170px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
        button:hover{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        h1{
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
            padding:20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
       .main{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
       }
        .news{
            padding:5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .description{
            margin:0;
            padding:20px 125px 30px 120px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#68a4c4;
            color:white;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .copyright{
            margin:0;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 760px) {
         .container{
            max-width:700px;  
            margin:0 auto;
         }
         .block{
            width:700px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;   
            
        } 
       
        button{
            width:700px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
    
        .description{
            width:700px;
            margin:0;
            padding:10px;
        
        }
        body{
            position:relative;
        }
        header{
            width:100%;
      }

        footer{
            width:100%;
        }
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <header><h1>Новости для котиков</h1></header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block "><p class="main">Новость 1</p><p class="news">Кому-то еще инресно узнать про короновирус?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 2</p><p class="news">Отменили минский полумарафон, зря готовились</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "> <p class="main">Новость 3</p><p class="news">Куда пойти на выходных когда нет денег?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 4</p><p class="news">Погода испортилась, а чего вы хотели от Сентября</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="description">
            <span>Что такое Lorem ipsum?</span><br>
            <br>Для заполнения страницы в веб-дизайне используют специально сгенерированный бессмысленный текст, получивший название Lorem ipsum. Перевод данной фразы в таком виде отсутствует, это искаженная цитата из труда Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного на латыни. Данное словосочетание — обрезка фразы «Dolorem ipsum», которая переводится как «саму боль».<br>
            <br><span>Почему он используется?</span><br>
            Использовать данный текст в книгопечатании начали еще 500 лет назад, чтобы продемонстрировать различные шрифты и внешний вид страницы заказчику. Благодаря такому заполнителю было видно, сколько строчек помещается на странице, подходит ли дизайн шрифтов для данной книги.<br>
            <br><span>Откуда он появился?</span><br>
            В самом деле, волшебные слова Lorem ipsum известны многим из тех, кто работает в области полиграфии или же веб-дизайна. Более того, эта абракадабра — только начало большого текста, и существуют программы, которые сгенерируют продолжение якобы бессмыслицы на псевдолатыни, выдав необходимое число символов, абзацев или параграфов. Для чего? Только для того, чтобы заполнить место текстом, похожим на обычный текст, изображенным латинским алфавитом, но внимания читателя не отвлекающим. <br>
            <br><span>Откуда его взять?</span><br>
            Такую штуку специалисты по дизайну называют «рыбой». И хотя сейчас Lorem ipsum используют главным образом специалисты по веб-дизайну, придумана эта «рыба» была еще в 16-м веке книгопечатниками для демонстрации шрифтов различных форм и размеров. Чтобы заказчик видел, как будет выглядеть печатная страница, сколько на ней окажется строчек и подходит ли используемый шрифт для цели, с которой печатается заказываемая книга. Вот печатники взяли длинный латинский текст и применили для презентации.</p>
    </div>
    <footer><p class="copyright"> &copy; Копирайт 2017</p></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во многих блоках в медиазапросе ширина не была 100%, бок-сайзинг у `.description` убрал, марджины справа лишние где-то были. Сравни код. Там просто невнимательность, ничего срашного. Нужно при таких проблемах пользоватсья дэв тулзами, смотреть и прям там же крутить цсс. Часто это решает вот такие проблемы. Где-то забыть что-то изменить - это нормально. ;)

```css
body{
            margin:0;
        }
        .container{
            max-width:980px;
            height:auto;
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        img{
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        header{
            min-width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#c2c2c2;
        }
        .block{
            width:170px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top:20px;
               
        }
        button{
            width:170px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
        button:hover{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        h1{
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
            padding:20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
       .main{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
       }
        .news{
            padding:5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .description{
            margin:0;
            padding:20px 125px 30px 120px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#68a4c4;
            color:white;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .copyright{
            margin:0;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 760px) {
       
         .container{
            max-width:100%;  
            margin:0 auto;
         }
         .container > img {
          width:100%;
         }
         .block{
            width:100%;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;   
            margin-right: 0;
        } 
       
        button{
            width:100%;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
    
        .description{
            width:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body{
            position:relative;
        }
        header{
            width:100%;
      }

        footer{
            width:100%;
        }
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://u.9111s.ru/uploads/202002/06/69a8db387d5ed5e5abf1a71a592c184e.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <header><h1>Новости для котиков</h1></header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block "><p class="main">Новость 1</p><p class="news">Кому-то еще инресно узнать про короновирус?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 2</p><p class="news">Отменили минский полумарафон, зря готовились</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "> <p class="main">Новость 3</p><p class="news">Куда пойти на выходных когда нет денег?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 4</p><p class="news">Погода испортилась, а чего вы хотели от Сентября</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="description">
            <span>Что такое Lorem ipsum?</span><br>
            <br>Для заполнения страницы в веб-дизайне используют специально сгенерированный бессмысленный текст, получивший название Lorem ipsum. Перевод данной фразы в таком виде отсутствует, это искаженная цитата из труда Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного на латыни. Данное словосочетание — обрезка фразы «Dolorem ipsum», которая переводится как «саму боль».<br>
            <br><span>Почему он используется?</span><br>
            Использовать данный текст в книгопечатании начали еще 500 лет назад, чтобы продемонстрировать различные шрифты и внешний вид страницы заказчику. Благодаря такому заполнителю было видно, сколько строчек помещается на странице, подходит ли дизайн шрифтов для данной книги.<br>
            <br><span>Откуда он появился?</span><br>
            В самом деле, волшебные слова Lorem ipsum известны многим из тех, кто работает в области полиграфии или же веб-дизайна. Более того, эта абракадабра — только начало большого текста, и существуют программы, которые сгенерируют продолжение якобы бессмыслицы на псевдолатыни, выдав необходимое число символов, абзацев или параграфов. Для чего? Только для того, чтобы заполнить место текстом, похожим на обычный текст, изображенным латинским алфавитом, но внимания читателя не отвлекающим. <br>
            <br><span>Откуда его взять?</span><br>
            Такую штуку специалисты по дизайну называют «рыбой». И хотя сейчас Lorem ipsum используют главным образом специалисты по веб-дизайну, придумана эта «рыба» была еще в 16-м веке книгопечатниками для демонстрации шрифтов различных форм и размеров. Чтобы заказчик видел, как будет выглядеть печатная страница, сколько на ней окажется строчек и подходит ли используемый шрифт для цели, с которой печатается заказываемая книга. Вот печатники взяли длинный латинский текст и применили для презентации.</p>
    </div>
    <footer><p class="copyright"> &copy; Копирайт 2017</p></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Alex, спасибо большое! :) Действительно работает. Можно еще Вам задать вопрос? При сужении экрана картинка выпадает из верстки, она привязана к контейнеру. Какие параметры нужно ей задать?

Comment: @MariaMasterova добавил картинку и цсс. Картинке так же ширину 100% дал.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и Ваше время! Хорошего вечера!